# JavaFX: how do I write and observable list to a text file, which has user-defined object class?

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFX: how do I write and observable list to a text file, which has user-defined object class?

ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Preferably using the BufferedWriter class.

Comment: But an observable list is different from an ordinary list?

Comment: `ObservableList` is a subinterface of `List` (read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)), so anything you can do with a `List`, you can do with an `ObservableList`.